# How can I develop in C# from my Mac?

Tags: macos, monodevelop

I have a virtual windows 7 machine that lives in the cloud on a server at work. I use a thin client to access the desktop and it works very well. When I'm at work, I'd have no idea there isn't a huge desktop sitting under my desk.

I also have a MacBook Pro.

I mapped my dev folder and mounted it to my Mac desktop. Will something like Monodevelop open my c# solutions? On my windows machine I can right click the solution to build, can I do something similar on the Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I develop cross-platform. With Mono, C# is one of the most ubiquitous languages. If your target application is Windows only, however, I would not recommend spending time on the intricacies involved in making it work with Mono.

I use VMWare Fusion and run Windows as a VM with a full working solution for the project on it - including Visual Studio and SQL Server. I then swipe between my OS X and Windows desktops as the needs require. This approach works best if your work has the correct licenses for Windows and the development software. It can be done on the cheap with an unused Windows license and the free versions of VS and SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks. I can access my client using Citrix Receiver for Mac. I wasn't aware I could swap between desktops though. Can you tell I've had a Mac for 2 days? Thanks guys!

Comment: If you have a touch-pad then the 3-finger swipe left or right moves between desktops. Swipe up shows the desktops at the top of the screen.